# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n/versions’: Permission denied

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

When I run `npm install n -g` on my computer (Ubuntu), I have these errors:

```
➜  ~  npm install -g n

/home/joes/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/n ->          /home/joes/.nvm/v0.10.38/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
n@2.0.2 /home/joes/.nvm/v0.10.38/lib/node_modules/n`

➜  ~  n

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n/versions ’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n/versions ’: Permission denied
find: '/usr/local/n/versions': No such file or directory`
Error: no installed version
```

Comment: what solution you found and why you can't use it ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you logged in as root user on your ubuntu machine? If not, try running the commands with `sudo`.

You also may have to [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/chown.1.html) the `/usr/local/n` directory to your user.

It's often one of these that cause the permission denied error you're seeing.

Comment: thanks ,but still have some errs:

    ➜  ~  n 4.1.0
install : node-v4.1.0
mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/4.1.0
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/n/versions/node/4.1.0’: Permission denied

  Error: sudo required`

    ➜  ~  sudo n 4.1.0
`sudo: unable to resolve host root
[sudo] password for joes: 
sudo: n: command not found`

Comment: @cnio check this discussion, I found it by googling your error. May help solve it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/466122/why-i-got-unable-to-resolve-host-when-i-do-sudo

Comment: > You also may have to chown the /usr/local/n directory to your user.

How exactly?